# SML interpreter.My Div func is working but i am having issue with my Minus func. I want it to give an error when the passed error is not a number

Tags: computer-science, sml, smlnj

```
datatype exp = Int of int | Minus of exp * exp | Div of exp * exp;


datatype value = CVal of int 
               | FnVal of string * exp * (string * value) list 
               | Error of string;

fun eval (Int x) _ = CVal x 
  | eval (Div (e1, e2)) ctx = let val (CVal x) = eval e1 ctx
                                  val (CVal y) = eval e2 ctx
                              in if y = 0
                                 then Error "Division by zero error"
                                 else CVal (x div y)
                              end
  | eval (Minus (e1, e2)) ctx = let val (CVal x) = eval e1 ctx
                                    val (CVal y) = eval e2 ctx
                                in if x <> Int orelse y <> Int
                                   then Error "Minus error : not an integer"
                                   else CVal (x - y)
                                end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Int` is not a value, it's a constructor. You can't compare it to anything.
It's also a constructor of `exp` values, not of integers.

If you look at your definition,

```
datatype value = CVal of int 
...
```

it's clear that `x` and `y`*must* be integers, just like in the division case.
If you want to check types, you need to do that for division too, and you need to do that *before*  you match with `CVal x` and `CVal y`.

This gets very messy if you try do it all in a single function, so I would write some evaluation-helper functions; something like this:

```
fun divide (CVal _) (CVal 0) = Error "Division by zero"
  | divide (CVal x) (CVal y) = CVal (x div y)
  | divide _ _ = Error "Division error: not an integer";

fun subtract (CVal x) (CVal y) = CVal (x - y)
  | subtract _ _ = Error "Subtraction error: not an integer";

fun eval (Int x) _ = CVal x 
  | eval (Div (e1, e2)) ctx = let val x = eval e1 ctx
                                  val y = eval e2 ctx
                              in
                                  divide x y
                              end
  | eval (Minus (e1, e2)) ctx = let val x = eval e1 ctx
                                    val y = eval e2 ctx
                                in
                                    subtract x y
                                end;
```